# ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib

Brand new to Python (typically program in MSDN C#) and I'm trying to make use of the matplotlib to generate some graphics from .csv files

I've downloaded & installed Python as well as Anaconda onto my Windows 10 machine, the versions are Python 3.5.2 and Anaconda 4.1.1

I open up the Python "notepad" interface and do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3],[3,2,1])

plt.show()
```

but when I run the code I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

I've looked at some other posts for this but they all seem to be in regard to Mac OSX or Linux. Some have pointed to multiple installs of matplotlib, but I haven't turned up such a situation so far. What might be causing this, or how can I troubleshoot it?

**Edit:

The path returned to me from the import sys recommended in the comments gave me this response

> ['C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\Desktop',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python35.zip',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages',
>
> 'C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-26.1.1-py3.5.egg']

Comment: Try this command: conda install matplotlib.

Comment: Installing on Windows can be done with `python -m pip install matplotlib`, if you have pip installed.

Comment: Where is your matplotlib install directory? Is it that directory in your path? (You can check your path in Python by using `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`.)

Comment: @Adnan the install command shows me that matplotlib is already installed in appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Comment: @SamiraN the directory command you recommended seemed to return multiple results - I'll post it in the original question since it's kind of long, but I don't see matplotlib in there anywhere

Comment: If matplotlib is in `AppData\local\continuum...` and your python path doesn't contain that, then you might have a problem indeed.

Comment: @AlexWatts When you try to import a module in Python, the interpreter will search the directories listed in `sys.path` for a module with that name. If your `matplotlib` install directory isn't in `sys.path`, then it won't be able to find `matplotlib`. I'd recommend copying matplotlib from its current install location and moving it to `C:\...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages`.

Comment: So you downloaded Python and Anaconda? And you are typing the above into the IDLE? What do you get if you type `where python` into cmd?

Comment: @Mr.F that command returns AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe.     It was my understanding that python was a stand-alone program, and then Anaconda was a packet manager that would allow you download, install, and update different version of python and its associated plugins. Is this incorrect?

Comment: @SamiraN I copied matplotlib and matplotlib-1.5.1-py3.5.egg-info from my Anaconda directory into the site-packages directory for Python, ran the code again, and got an error in import matplotlib.pyplot AND numpy as well now. Interestingly, when I ran the python.exe I found as a result of WHERE PYTHON command and entered the code via that command window, it displayed my graphic without showing any errors

Comment: Anaconda ships with a python.exe for the version you downloaded. The Anaconda version of the IDLE is called `spyder` so if you run the code in your question in that I think it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You essentially have 2 versions of python on your system - the standard one you downloaded and the one that ships with Anaconda. When you are running code in the IDLE you are using the standard version (in `C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe`) where `matplotlib` isn't installed which is why you are getting the error.

You need to use the Anaconda version (`C:\Users\a.watts.ISAM-NA\AppData\Local\continuum\anaconda3\python.exe`) that comes with the scientific stuff already setup. It looks like your system is using this one from the `cmd` so if you run scripts from there it should use the Anaconda version. If you want to use something more interactive you can also use `spyder` - the Anaconda version of the IDLE - or run `jupyter notebook` from cmd to get a browser based platform for interactive development

Comment: That would be it! Because Anaconda labels its IDLE as Spyder, I wasn't aware it was an environment that you coded in. The code runs with no errors now though!